# symfony form collection customization

Tags: forms, symfony

I have created symfony using collection

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>{{ 'Comments'|trans }}:</legend>
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ form_label(form.category) }}</td>
                <td>{{ form_widget(form.category) }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">{{ form_errors(form.category) }}</td></tr>

            <tr><td colspan="2">{{ form_label(form.comment) }}</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">{{ form_widget(form.comment) }}</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">{{ form_errors(form.comment) }}</td></tr>

            <tr><td colspan="2">{{ form_label(form.documents) }}</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">{{ form_widget(form.documents) }}</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">{{ form_errors(form.documents) }}</td></tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    {{ form_widget(form.save) }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
</fieldset>
```

but I'am stuck with one thing I need form erros after upload input

```
<tr><td colspan="2">{{ form_label(form.documents) }}</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">{{ form_widget(form.documents) }}</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">{{ form_errors(form.documents) }}</td></tr>
```

But here's what I am getting and what I need to achieve:

[image]

How can I achieve such behavior?

Comment: Is `documents` your collection ?

Comment: yes, for simple field it's enough to to change ordering, as in example code, but for collection, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, by creating custom form row template as shown in [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html)

```
{# Path/ToBundle/Forms/fields.html.twig #}
{% block form_row %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <div class="form_row">
            {{ form_label(form) }}
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```

Then I included it before rending form:

```
{% form_theme form with 'PathToBundle:Forms:fields.html.twig' %}
<fieldset>
    <legend>{{ 'Comments'|trans }}:</legend>
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    ...
```

And lastly I render form row using included template:

```
<tr><td colspan="2">{{ form_row(form.documents) }}</td></tr>
```

Though I'll still need to improve html markup, but it works fine, and renders elements, in needed order.